# How to connect the frontend folder with backend folder in laravel

Tags: laravel, connect, laravel-11

I have two separate folder frontend and backend. frontend folder have html, CSS, JS code. backend folder have business logic. how to connect both folder.

I want to connect the both folder to run the code. and saw the result.